# How to Rename Column name based on condition in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, identity-column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blZMz.png)i have a dataframe which contains 4 columns and i have to rename columns based on its items.
example : 
if majority of columns items are string rename it to Name 
if majority are floats rename it to values
please find attached image for reference.

Comment: can you add the sample code segment for the reference?

Comment: Can you attach the image as you have promised?

Comment: i have added image.. i want to make a dynamic code where A should be Renamed with AOR and D and E should be given Value1 and Value2 Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

we can use `select_dtypes` and pass them to a list to count the length.

```
col_floats = df.select.dtypes(include='float').columns.tolist()
col_strings = df.select.dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist()

if len(col_floats) > len(col_strings):
    df.columns.map(lambda x : 'Values '  + x)
else:
    df.columns.map(lambda x : 'AOR ' + x)
```

you can edit the logic for your use case, but its hard to say what you want without ur sample dataset and example output.

## Edit

Looking at your DF I see that you want to test for the numbers in each dataframe series to see which is greater, as we don't have a textual sample of your dataframe its hard to say but something like this could work :

```
new_name = []

for columns in df.columns:
    n = pd.to_numeric(df[f'{columns}'],errors='coerce')
    if n.isna().sum() > n.dropna().count(): # tests if strings are greater than numbers
        new_name.append('AOR') 
    else:
        new_name.append('Value')

new_col_dict = dict(zip(df.columns.tolist(),new_name))
```

you could then simply assign the new_names to your column and check the output with the `new_col_dict` dictionary.

testing on my own dataframe where I added in some random ints into object columns I got the following :

```
    {'Business Date': 'Value', 
 'First Name': 'AOR',
 'Hours': 'Value',
 'Last Name': 'AOR',
 'Number': 'Value',
 'Pay Code': 'Value',  # I added more ints than strings to this column and the test above worked.
 'Pay Time End': 'Value',
 'Pay Time Start': 'Value',
 'Site Name': 'AOR'}
```

Comment: i have added image of my dataset

Comment: @AmrutaVadnere please share a text sample of your dataframe next time.

Comment: @AmrutaVadnere no problemo bhaji (= can you accept the answer (green tick) if you are happy with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this will work for you

What is happening here is the `df[col].count()` will count the numebr of numeric values in a column. Assuming that hte length of the columns is 10, if count is more than 6, it is assumed that the columns has majority of numebrs & changed to name `nums`. However, naming multiple column same is not a good idea.

```
cols = df.columns
for col in cols:
    if (df[col].count()/df.shape[0]) > 0.5:
        df.rename({col:'nums'}, axis=1, inplace =True)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: it is renaming every columns as nums

Comment: can you paste you data directly in the question as text so that I can run th code on it? Also, updated the code a little bit, try once now.

Comment: this code gives this error - The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().i have added image of my dateframe